# "No Method Declared with Objective-C Selector 'playPause:'" & "Use of Unresolved Identifier UIBarButtonItem"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode7

[I'm Making a music player and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error in my code. I'm new to coding and would highly appreciate some help (This is the image of the code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sH2b.jpg)

Comment: Write your code and error in your post instead of attaching its snapshot! Also read this: [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a mistake, replace it `UIBarButtonItem.play`with  `UIBarButtonSystemItem.play`